# How can I close my app in background when click on button in android

Tags: android

I am showing a message on a button click ("plz verify Email."). And when the user click on the button then browser will be open and I want to redirect my app into first activity in background.

I want my app to return to his first state when the user come back on it.

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks the button to close the dialog, then from the calling activity create an Intent and start the Browser with `startActivityForResult()`.

In the same activity, implement `onActivityResult()`.  In there, create an Intent and start your initial activity with `startActivity()`.

For more information, refer to the Android docs on [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) and [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can set a flag when you start the intent, and test it in onResume

when it was true, finish it self and start the first acrivity.
Buy the way, set the launchMode of the first activity to singleTop

Answer (score 0):

Just call finish(); whenever you want to finish the Activity.

Comment: but when I call finish();then it will finish current activity but I want to open app from the login page means first activity.